# Why "df" and "du" show different space usage on /storage/emulated/0?

Tags: internal-storage

My Moto X (first generation) has a 11.9GB of user storage, almost all of which is used. Here is the relevant line from `df`:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/storage/emulated/0     11.9G    10.3G     1.6G   4096
```

But when I go to the mount point and run `du`:

```
/storage/emulated/0 $ du -hs .                                   
5.0G    .
```

There are no mount points under `/storage/emulated/0`, so it can't be the [files hidden under mount points issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/275206/disk-full-du-tells-different-how-to-further-investigate).

Android Settings and ES File Explorer show numbers that corroborate this, with ~10GB used but a breakdown that doesn't total more than 5GB.

Is 10GB actually being used? If so, how can I find out where the other 5GB is going?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/{x}` is typically symlinked to somewhere on `/data`, so I would guess in both of these cases the available size is the total size of `/data`, but you're only running `du` on the one subdirectory. Try `ls -l /storage/emulated` (or possibly up one level, `ls -l /storage`) to see where it's pointing, then you might be able to use that to see if it's accurate.

Comment: It looks like on my system `/storage/emulated/0` is a loop mount of `/data/media`. Unfortunately, I can't view `/data` itself. Maybe it's time to root this phone :(

Comment: You need not to root the device yet. Tell us (screenshots) what [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) shows you.

Comment: Related: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)